# Error when renewing Let's Encrypt SSL certificate

Tags: powershell, azure, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

This is part of the error:

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.RenewCertificate ---> System.ArgumentException: 'authority' should be in Uri format Parameter name`

When I was instaling de aplication through the PowerShell at the time to execute this command ([the tutorial that i followed](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16420/Lets-Encrypt-Azure-Web-Apps-the-Free-and-Easy-Way/20073#.WjOVMXm1uUl))

`$ app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName {some display name} -HomePage $ uri -IdentifierUris $ uri -Password $ password`

It showed this error:

`ConvertTo-SecureString: Can not bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
At line: 1 char: 44
+ $ password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ _. password -AsPlainText - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand`

So I "fix it" with `$ password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ password -AsPlainText -Force`.

How can I solve the error?

Thanks

Comment: Use `new-azurermadapplication` to create new AAD application with password, should convert to securestring.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to create new AAD application with password, `-password` requires  **SecureString**.

Here is the example:

```
PS E:\> $SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
PS C:\> New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "NewApplication" -HomePage "http://www.microsoft.com" -IdentifierUris "http:
//NewApplication" -Password $SecureStringPassword
```

Required parameter:

[image]

More information about this command, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-5.7.0).